# Can't find properties file when running gradle test

Tags: java, junit, gradle

I am using gradle to build and test my application. I use the command

```
gradle test
```

But the testing, which works perfectly when run from within eclipse, fails when run using gradle. My test is defined below and the properties file that it cannot find is in both these folders:

/home/user/Development/git/myproject/src/main/java/com/mycompany/config
/home/user/Development/git/myproject/src/test/resources

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {      ApplicationConfig.class })
public class WebImportTest {
    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private JestClient jestClient;
```

my java configuration looks like so:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.mycompany" })
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/mycompany/config/myproject.properties")
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;
```

I am not experience enough in order to figure out what is the cause of this

```
:myproject is getting tests from [task ':test']
:compileJava
Note: /home/user/Development/git/myproject/src/main/java/com/mycompany/entities/generated/Keys.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:instrument SKIPPED
:copyCoberturaDatafile SKIPPED
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test

com.mycompany.myProject.DBConnectionTest > initializationError FAILED
java.lang.Exception

com.mycompany.myProject.WebImportTest > testWebImport FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException
            Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Why is the properties file not found?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The properties file needs to go into `src/main/resources/com/mycompany/config`.

Comment: That was it. That mean that if the java configuration file is used during a test it will try to fetch a property file from the corresponding resources folder. Nice. Thanks

Comment: Wait a second. If the properties file is only needed for testing, it should go under `src/test/resources/com/mycompany/config`. If it should be shipped along with the production code, it should go under `src/main/resources/com/mycompany/config`.

Comment: Is there no way to configure build.gradle to have property file in custom location like in config directory of project root?