# Can't find properties file when running gradle test outside of Springs framework

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to load a configuration file from a Java class in a Gradle based project. I'm using java.util.Properties to load a file relative to the project (so I am not required to hardcode a path to the config file).

I've looked at an almost exact problem, 
[Can't find properties file when running gradle test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378763/cant-find-properties-file-when-running-gradle-test), however, I'm not using Springs framework, so the answers look very different.

My current code looks like this:

```
String filename = "config.properties";

input =  Config.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);
if (input == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("config " + filename + " not found");
}
```

I've placed my config file in just about every folder of the project. I've used the default gradle resources folder, src/test/resources, but no luck.

Should the config file be placed near the .java file, .class file (probably not happening because .class output is dynamic from gradle) or in the resources folder?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code `Config.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");`, you are looking for the resource `config.properties` in the same package that your class is. The path given to [`Class.getResourceAsStream(name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) is relative to the location of the class in the package hierarchy.

If you place the resources under `src/test/resources`, then it will end up at the root of your final jar, so you can look for it at `/config.properties`, using an absolute path.

Comment: Nice, terse explanation - and solved my problem. In my various permutations, I missed the leading slash thinking that would search for file from root of my system.